# We can't process your payment right now, so please try again later. We're sorry for the inconvenience

Tags: paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to send amount to user's paypal account using Paypal Adaptive Payments, all working fine it redirects me to paypal and ask for login but when I click on ligin it give me this error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are well!

Use PayPal Payouts to send money to multiple people at the same time.

To send a payout, you need:

1. A PayPal business account
2. Each recipient's email address, a domestic mobile number, or payer ID (an encrypted PayPal account number)
3. Payment amount (per recipient)
4. Currency code (one currency per payout)
5. Note to recipient (required for Venmo accounts, optional for PayPal accounts)

Below mentioned URL would help you choose the best integration option,

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/.

API & SFTP Batch Payout requires special permission from PayPal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to sent money to user paypal account from my website's admin panel. Is there any way to do so? I am using laravel framework for developing.

Answer (score 1):

Adaptive Payments has been deprecated since December of 2017, do not attempt to use it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, than what I can use instad of Adaptive Payments ? I want to send payments from my laravel app to user's paypal account.

Comment: I tried to use PaypalMassPayment but it's also give error. like Permission deniede. You do not have permission to make this API call. I am stuck for two days

Comment: Mass Payments is an old API, the current one is Payouts. See information about requesting access here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/payouts/integrate/prerequisites/#get-access-to-paypal-payouts